# nodejs Agent does not drop the connection after timeout

Tags: node.js

I want to configure the http.Agent to drop the connection after 5 seconds but it never happens.

The server is configured to drop the connection after 20 seconds (for this test)

The connection is dropped after 20 seconds (server drops the connection istead of the client)

```
var http = require('http');

var myAgent = new http.Agent({keepAlive:true, keepAliveMsecs:5000});

var client = http.get({host:'localhost', agent:myAgent}, function(incMsg){
    incMsg.on('data', function(chunk){ console.log(chunk.toString()) });
    incMsg.on('end', function(){ console.log('-- END OF MESSAGE --') });    
});
```

How can I configure the Agent to drop the connection for its http clients ?

I'm fairly new in http server client connections  so sorry if I missed something obvious but I can't google it out

Answer (score 2):

agent option `timeout:5000` must be used instead of the `keepAliveMsecs:5000`

here is the working code

```
var http = require('http');

var myAgent = new http.Agent({keepAlive:true, timeout:5000});

var client = http.get({host:'localhost', agent:myAgent}, function(incMsg){
    incMsg.on('data', function(chunk){ console.log(chunk.toString()) });
    incMsg.on('end', function(){ console.log('-- END OF MESSAGE --') });    
});
```